# getting errors implement vue pagination plugin in Vue 3 component in Laravel 10 project

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I have set up a Laravel 10 project in that i have vue 3 component . In there i have implemented a vue 3 plugin [vue-awesome-pagination](https://github.com/peshanghiwa/vue-awesome-paginate) . It's working But the  data is not getting paginated when i reload the page or click on the pages number. when i reload the page all the data results are showing up. I'm not getting any error or warning related to it.[image: pagination]

**App.js file**

```
import "./bootstrap";

import { createApp } from "vue";
import Example from "./components/Example.vue";
import TeamMember from "./components/TeamMembers.vue";
import Pagination from "./components/Pagination.vue";
import Blogs from "./components/Blogs.vue";
// import TeamPagination from "./components/TeamPagination.vue";
import TeamAwesome from "./components/TeamAwesome.vue";


const app = createApp({
    // components: {
    // Example,
    // },
});

app.component("example", Example);
app.component("team-member", TeamMember);
app.component("pagination", Pagination);
app.component("blog-post", Blogs);
app.component("team-awesome", TeamAwesome);


// import the package
import VueAwesomePaginate from "vue-awesome-paginate";

// import the necessary css file
import "vue-awesome-paginate/dist/style.css";

app.use(VueAwesomePaginate).mount("#app");
```

**Vue Component Code:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- Category Section -->
        <div class="isotop_nav" id="categories-container">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" :class="{ 'active': selectedCategory === null }"
                        @click.prevent="handleCategoryClick(null)">
                        All
                    </a>
                </li>
                <!-- Loop through categories and generate links -->
                <li v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id">
                    <a href="#" :class="{ 'active': selectedCategory === category.name }"
                        @click.prevent="handleCategoryClick(category.name)">
                        {{ category . name }}
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Team Section -->
        <div class="leadership_list onTeam_sec">
            <div  id="filtered-team-members"  class="row justify-content-center">

                    <!-- Use Vue data properties and methods -->
                    <!-- console members data -->

                        <div v-for="(member) in members" :key="member.id" :data-category="member.category ? member.category.name : ''" class="col-xxl-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-4 category-item">
                            <div class="leadership_list_info">
                                <span>
                                    <img :src="`/uploads/${member.profile_picture}`" alt="leadership profile" />
                                </span>
                                <a href="#"><strong>{{ member.name }}</strong></a>
                                <p>{{ member . role }}</p>
                                <div class="contactSocial_infoList">
                                    <ul>
                                        <!-- Use Vue data properties -->
                                        <li v-if="member.twitter_link">
                                            <a :href="member.twitter_link" target="_blank" class="s_tw">
                                                <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li v-if="member.salesforce_link">
                                            <a :href="member.salesforce_link" target="_blank" class="s_inst">
                                                <i class="fa-brands fa-salesforce"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li v-if="member.linkedIn_link">
                                            <a :href="member.linkedIn_link" target="_blank" class="s_link">
                                                <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- <vue-awesome-paginate :total-items="totalItems" :items-per-page="5" :max-pages-shown="5" v-model="currentPage" :on-click="filterTeamMembers"></vue-awesome-paginate> -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="pagination">
                            <!-- :on-click="filterTeamMembers" -->
                            <vue-awesome-paginate
                            :total-items="totalItems"
                            :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
                            :max-pages-shown="pagesShown"
                            v-model="currentPage"
                            :on-click="filterTeamMembers"
                            @page-clicked="handlePageChange"
                            :container-class="'pagination-container'"
                            ></vue-awesome-paginate>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style>
  .pagination-container {
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 10px;
  }
  .paginate-buttons {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
    border: 1px solid rgb(217, 217, 217);
    color: black;
  }
  .paginate-buttons:hover {
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
  }
  .active-page {
    background-color: #3498db;
    border: 1px solid #3498db;
    color: white;
  }
  .active-page:hover {
    background-color: #2988c8;
  }
</style>
<script>
    import axios from "axios";

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                 members: [],
                //     members: [
                //     { id: 1, name: 'John Doe', role: 'Developer', twitter_link: 'https://twitter.com/johndoe' },
                //     { id: 2, name: 'Jane Doe', role: 'Designer', linkedIn_link: 'https://linkedin.com/janedoe' },
                // ],
                categories: [],
                selectedCategory: null,
                totalItems : 1,
                currentPage:1,
                itemsPerPage: 3,
                pagesShown:1,


            };
        },
        components: {
            // Pagination,
            // s VueAwesomePaginate
        },
        mounted() {
            // Fetch initial team members (all members)
            //
            this.fetchCategories();

            // this.filterTeamMembers();
        },
        methods: {

            // function to fetch categories
            fetchCategories() {
                console.log('Fetch Categories Clicked');
                // axios.get(`/our-team/categories?page=${page}&total=${this.total}`)
                axios.get(`/our-team/categories`)
                // const endpoint = `/our-team/categories?page=${this.currentPage}&total=${this.totalMembers}`;
                //     axios.get(endpoint)
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log('API Response for categories:', response.data);
                        this.categories = response.data.categories;
                        this.members = response.data.members;
                        this.totalItems = response.data.members.length;
                        this.pagesShown = Math.ceil(this.totalItems / this.itemsPerPage);
                        console.log(this.members);
                        // console.log(this.totalMembers);
                        // this.selectedCategory = null;
                        // this.totalPages = Math.ceil(this.totalMembers / this.perPage);
                        // this.totalChunks = Math.ceil(this.totalPages / this.chunk);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error fetching categories:', error);
                    });
            },

            // Function to fetch and display filtered team members
            filterTeamMembers(member ) {
                const endpoint = member ? `/our-team/${member}` : '/our-team/all';
                // const endpoint = member ? `/our-team/${member}?page=${this.currentPage}` : `/our-team/all?page=${this.currentPage}`;
                axios.get(endpoint)
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log('API Response:', response.data);
                        // this.members = response.data.members;
                        this.members = response.data.members;
                        // this.totalItems = response.data.members.length;
                        // this.totalPages = Math.ceil(this.totalMembers / this.perPage);
                        // this.totalChunks = Math.ceil(this.totalPages / this.chunk);
                        // this.totalItems = response.data.total;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error fetching team members:', error);
                    });
            },

            handleCategoryClick(category) {
                // Set the selected category
                this.selectedCategory = category;
                // this.currentPage = 1;
                // Filter team members based on the selected category
                 this.filterTeamMembers(category);
            },

            handlePageChange(data) {
                // Set the current page
                this.currentPage = data.currentPage;
                // Filter team members based on the selected category
                // this.filterTeamMembers(this.selectedCategory);
            },

        },

    }
</script>
```

**Controller Code:**

```
    public function filterByCategory(Request $request, $category)
    {
        // Log::info('Received category:', ['category' => $category]);
        if ($category === 'all' || $category === null) {
            // If the category is 'All', return all team members
            $members = TeamMember::where('status', 'opened')->orderBy('order_column')->paginate(3);
        } else {
            // If it's a specific category, filter by that category
            $categoryModel = TeamCategory::where('name', 'like', $category)->first();

            if (!$categoryModel) {
                // Handle the case when the category is not found
                return response()->json([
                    'members' => []
                ]);
            }

            // $members = $categoryModel->teamMembers;
            $members = $categoryModel->teamMembers()->where('status', 'opened')->orderBy('order_column')->paginate(3);
        }

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response()->json([
                'members' => $members,
                // 'categories' => $categories,
                // 'selectedCategory' => $selectedCategory,
            ]);
        }

        return view('our-team.our-team', compact('members', 'categories'));
    }


    public function getTeam(Request $request, $category = null)
    {
        $membersQuery = TeamMember::where('status', 'opened')->orderBy('order_column');
        $categories = TeamCategory::all();
        $selectedCategory = null;

        if ($category && $category !== 'all') {
            $selectedCategory = TeamCategory::where('name', 'like', $category)->first();
            if ($selectedCategory) {
                $membersQuery->where('team_category_id', $selectedCategory->id);
            }
        }

        $members = $membersQuery->get();

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response()->json(['members' => $members, 'categories' => $categories, 'selectedCategory' => $selectedCategory]);
        }

        return view('our-team.our-team', compact('members', 'categories', 'selectedCategory'));
    }
```

Kindly tell me how to implement the dynamic pagination where i can fetch the data and show through pagination.

Tried: I tried to implement it according to the documentation but it is not working .

Expect:  I want to implement dynamic pagination which fetch the data from the apis and show it through pagination.